# Specify URL to post into a Nested JSON object property using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

here is a copy of my db.json file

```
"users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Toyeeb",
      "address": "Aja",
      "favorites": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Amala",
          "price": "1800"
        }
      ],
      "email": "tboynoni@yahoo.com",
      "password": "toyeeb1"
    }
  ]
```

now i'm trying to post into 'Favorites' using ajax jquery but all the URL i tried are not working, please help me guys...thanks

have tried

`'http://localhost:3000/users?_embed=favorites/'
'http://localhost:3000/users/1/favorites'
'http://localhost:3000/users?id=1favorites/'
'http://localhost:3000/users?favorites/'
'http://localhost:3000/users.favorites/'`

Comment: Post you Jquey ajax call sample.

Comment: you can't directly ajax into a json file, you need a server side language to update the json file

Comment: `$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:'http://localhost:3000/users?_embed=favorites/',
      data: ele,
      success: function(){
        alert("Added to Favorites");
        populateFavFood();
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("error");
      }
    })`

Comment: thats the code i'm using

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/users?_embed=favorites/',
  data: ele,
  success: function () {
    alert("Added to Favorites");
    populateFavFood();
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("error");
  }
})
```